# Pull Profile2 Fields into Product Display node based on selection of Profile Owner

Tags: entities, users

I want to select an artist using a selector and have several fields from their profile2 profile ( main profile ) appear in the product creation form. I can select the artist now, but I need to have about 9 fields reference the selection and pull their info from the same profile.